# How Should I Check if an ArrayController's Content isDirty in Ember

Tags: templates, ember.js, model, ember-data

In my application's templates I'm using:

```
  {{#if exampleModel.isDirty }}

  {{else}}

  {{/if}}
```

... to show different Ui depending on whether the View's Model isDirty. This works nicely.

However I have another view backed by an ArrayController subclass. Again I would like to change the UI based on whether or not there are any dirty items in the ArrayController. I have tried:

```
{{#if controller.isDirty }}
```

and

```
{{#if controller.content.isDirty }}
```

But although neither generate exceptions, neither evaluate to true at any point, even when Models in the ArrayController subclass are dirty.

**What is the correct way to check if any of the models decorated by an ArrayController are dirty?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could define a computed property on your ArrayController:

```
isDirty : function(){
  this.forEach(function(model){
    var dirty = false;
    if(model.get("isDirty"))
      dirty = true;
  });
  return dirty;
}.property("content.@each.isDirty")
```

So key is the **proper declaration of the property dependencies**.

**Update** to interesting question in comments: **Why is this functionality not baked into Ember?**

Regarding your comment of baked in functionality: Your are looking at Ember with ember-data in mind. I personally do not use it with ember-data. So in my case this functionality would be nonsense. So one could discuss to add this as a Mixin to Ember in order to facilitate integration a little bit more.

Example:

```
Ember.IsArrayDirtyMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    isDirty : function(){
      this.forEach(function(model){
        var dirty = false;
        if(model.get("isDirty"))
          dirty = true;
      });
      return dirty;
    }.property("content.@each.isDirty")
});

App.YourController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.IsArrayDirtyMixin,{
    .... // your stuff
});

// shorter version proposed by pjlammertyn in the comments
Ember.IsArrayDirtyMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    isDirty : function(){
      return !this.every(function (model) { return !model.get('isDirty'); });
    }.property("content.@each.isDirty")
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems strange that this wouldn't be baked in. I couldn't get your code to work. For some reason the `return true` doesn't exit the loop, so I had to use a flag: `var dirty = false;
    this.forEach(function(model){
      if(model.get("isDirty")){
        dirty = true;
      }
    });
    return dirty;`

Comment: Good catch. I will update my answer accordingly. I guess the return breaks the loop, but it does not perform again the return in the scope of 'isDirty'. Regarding your comment of baked in functionality: Your are looking at Ember with ember-data in mind. I personally do not use it with ember-data. So in my case this functionality would be nonsense. So one could discuss to add this as a Mixin to Ember in order to facilitate integration a little bit more.

Comment: Fair enough. Been using Ember with Ember-data since I started using it last week, so not exactly sure where one starts and the other stops yet.

Comment: even better:  Ember.IsArrayDirtyMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
 isDirty: function () {
  return !this.every(function (model) {
   return !model.get('isDirty');
  });
 }.property('content.@each.isDirty')
});

Comment: Yeah this also a nice variant. Will update my post accordingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or more simply, assuming you're in an `ArrayController`:

```
  ...
  hasChanged: function() {
    var records = this.get('model');
    return records.isAny('isDirty', true);
  }.property('model.@each.isDirty'),
  isNotDirty: Ember.computed.not('hasChanged'),
  ...
```

Really these patterns are so common I am surprised they are not built in.